# How to convert integer to string and get length of string

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

In my database there is a field `last_id` of type `integer`. The table contains several rows. Let's say the maximum value of `last_id` is 104050. Now I want to know the *length* of this integer.

As this is not possible I am trying to convert it into a string.

```
SELECT to_char(MAX(last_id),'99') FROM xxxx
```

I would expect this to yield 10 with type = text, but instead it returns ## type = text. 
Afterwards I would use `SELECT char_length(to_char(MAX(last_id),'99')) FROM xxx` which should return 2 ...

What is going wrong here?

Comment: The reason is the "fill mode" of the `to_char()` function. Using `to_char(last_id, 'FM99')` would probably solve your problem.

Comment: Why would you accept rjhdby's answer? Mine is shorter, better, earlier and actually correct.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you're right, I have fixed this now as it helped solve my problem first place

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) the `integer` value to `text`:

```
SELECT length(max(last_id)::text) FROM xxx;
```

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. AS a next step I would like to to do the following: Add spaces to the field last_id so that the length of that field is 10 instead of 6. So if it only has a length of 5 I want to add 5 spaces to it, if it is 4 I want to add 6. Is that possible?

Comment: @user3387124 Sure, pad right or left? But ask a *new question* please. This one was about finding out the length of an integer in text representation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are dealing with integers you can actually find the length of the number (or number of digits in the number) directly. Mathematically, the number of digits in an integer is one more than the floor of the log base 10 of the number.

You could use the following to find the length directly:

```
SELECT FLOOR(LOG(MAX(last_id))) + 1 FROM xxxx
```

Comment: Needless to say, this only works with positive integers.  Since in most systems, an id would be a positive integer, this wouldn't be a great limitation.  SELECT FLOOR(LOG(MAX(abs(last_id) ))) + 1 FROM xxxx should always work for the numeric part, though one might  want to add logic to increase the answer (in character-count) for negative numbers.  Example:   for -1000, as is, the formula I have in this comment would give 4 instead of 5, so the string conversion in others  answers would handle this case better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't work with postgresql, but after documentation read... Somthign like this.

SELECT character_length(cast(last_id as varchar(20))) from table